# How to write imaginary and real part of $\cos()/e^{z}$ as functions of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have found that $\cos(z) = \cos(x)\cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y)$, but from now, I don't know how to deal with the denominator $e^z$.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^z = e^{x + iy} = e^x e^{iy} = e^x (\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$$
Thus:
$$\frac{\cos(z)}{e^z} = \frac{\cos(x)\cosh(y) - i \sin(x)\sinh(y)}{e^x(\cos(y) + i \sin(y))} \\= \frac{1}{e^x (\cos^2(y) +\sin^2(y))} (\cos(x)\cosh(y) - i \sin(x)\sinh(y))(\cos(y) - i \sin(y)) \\ = e^{-x}(\cos(x)\cosh(y)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sinh(y)\sin(y)) - ie^{-x}(\sin(x)\sinh(y)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\cosh(y) \sin(y))$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
e^z \;\; =\;\; e^{x+iy} \;\; =\;\; e^xe^{iy}.
$$